# Can any one suggest a very basic book for fuzzy graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, textbook-recommendation, online-resources, fuzziness

Can anyone help with a very basic book on fuzzy graph theory for a beginner to it with good explanations.

Any video course online on fuzzy graph theory extensively to help understand please share link.

Kind help

Answer (score 2):

This would depend a bit on your background. If you are familiar with fuzzy sets, then [Fuzzy Graph Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319714066) by Mathew, Mordeson, and Malik offers a good overview. They also have a [follow-up volume](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319764535) with more specialized applications.

If you are not familiar with fuzzy sets, you could start with [Introduction to Fuzzy Graph Theory](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Introduction-to-Fuzzy-Graph-Theory-Pal/ed409d98e11d0732ef21e92a959fc6a657d1ac56), just to get a feeling for the field, but then you would want to first study fuzzy sets, perhaps by following this [online course.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZWTduVCrf8) (I have not found an online course specifically on fuzzy graphs.)